# How to trigger only the event that is being clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, target

I have two image sliders that both get fired even if I only click the arrow on one of them. I just want function to work on only the slider that is being clicked on.

I know that I need to use an event.target so that way it would only fire on the arrow that is being clicked. However, I am unsure of what the syntax would look like because everything I have tried keeps giving me an error.

Here is the Jquery that I have written

```
//Funtion for gallery slider
$(document).ready(function () {


    var arrowRight = document.querySelector('.gallery-arrow-right');
    var arrowLeft = document.querySelector('.gallery-arrow-left');

    var show = 4;
    var width = $('#slider').width() / show;
    console.log(width)

    var length = $('.slide').length;


    $('.slide').width(width);
    $('#slide-container').width(width * length)



    function sliderNext(e) {
        $('.slide:first-child').animate({
            marginLeft: -width + -35
        }, 'slow', function () {
            $(this).appendTo($(this).parent()).css({marginLeft: 0});
        });
    }

    function sliderPrev(e) {
      $('.slide:last-child').prependTo($('.slide:last-child').parent()).css({marginLeft:-width});
      $('.slide:first-child').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
      }, 'slow')
    }


    arrowRight.addEventListener('click', sliderNext )
    arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', sliderPrev )

});
```

Here is my html

```
  <section class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-slider" id="slider">
      <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">This is the gallery</h1>
      <div class="d-flex" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right:0; "id="slide-container" >
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="" src="/images/components/gallery_slider/Bathroom_slider.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="gallery-slider-title">Shop Bathroom</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="" src="/images/components/gallery_slider/Dining_slider.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="gallery-slider-title">Shop Dining</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="">
            <img class="" src="/images/components/gallery_slider/Diningroom_slider.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="gallery-slider-title">Shop Dining Room</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="" src="/images/components/gallery_slider/Kitchen_slider.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="gallery-slider-title">Shop Kitchen</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
          <a href="#">
            <img class="" src="/images/components/gallery_slider/Dining_slider.jpg" alt="">
            <p class="gallery-slider-title">Shop Slider</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-2x gallery-arrow-left" style="margin-right: 20px;"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-2x gallery-arrow-right"></i>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The arrows are children of a container of class `gallery`.  As such to contextually target the elements you want I suggest navigating to the gallery.  For instance:

```
$('.slide:first-child')
```

whould change to:

```
$(e.target).closest('.gallery').find('.slide:first-child')
```

Then you will only target the first slide in the gallery you are clicking in.  You will also have to do the same for your :last-child selectors.